# Star rating view in tableview using floatingview

Tags: ios

How to implement the star rating in the tableviewcell.
I need to implement the star rating in the tableview.

I have a tableview .And i have listed the data in the tableview.So now i need to implement the rating in the cell.How to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this as a reference https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html

Comment: i need to select the rates forrating how to do?

Comment: I haven't done anything with rating before. I just knew apple has a tutorial about it and i gave the link. I think the tutorial is good and might give you an idea how to implement rating in your app.  I would recommend you give a bit more info about your code and what you've tried. It will be easier for people to help.